# Fetching Flask Backend data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a basic HTML file where we have two inputs (number), and these inputs are wrapped inside a Form tag which sends a POST request to the backend. In the flask app I use python request module to grab data from https://fred.stlouisfed.org/ connvert this into dataframe and do some basic number crunching. I get the processed dataframe on which I have to calculate average, STD etc (some statistical measures) and to plot a chart. These are to be displayed in a `<div></div>`, using only javascript (**no jinja**) is it possible to that? Also can we stop the page reloading once the we click on Calculate (submit) button?

One method i found researching was to do the calculation in one end-point and then fetch that result using javascript using fetch API but I am not sure how to do that?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from api import fredApi,blsApi # custom built module


@app.route('/')
def labor_home():
    
    return render_template('labor-dashboard-html.html')

@app.route('/calculation', methods=['GET','POST'])
def calculation():
    if request.method=='POST':
       
       # get the form data (x,y)
       # get the series data and convert it into dataframe df
       # do some number crunching using x,y,df and have a new dataframe df2
       # return either average or STD or some other statistical metric 
       # metric= df2['a'].stat_func() 
       # x=df2['date']
       # y=df2['b']
       # will jsonify all the variable before returning
       return **metric,x,y**
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/labor-dashboard-css.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/calculation" method="POST">
<button type='submit'>Calculate</button>
<label for='input1' name='input1'>Input1</label>
<input type="number" name="input1" id="js-input1">
<label for="input2" name="input2">Input2</label>
<input type="number" name="input2" id="js-input2">
</form>

<div class="show-statistic></div>
<div class="show-chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

We can use CSS to make the HTML better. Now to main part, how to grab **metric,x,y** from the flask put it inside a variable in javascript file (avoiding inline javascript)? (after that we can then simply do a document.querySelector and put these values inside the div's)

Comment: you use AJAX in the client to call the server API without submitting the form and reloading the page. Read a tutorial on using the `fetch()` function.

Comment: and how should I get the variables returned from calculation() in javascript?

Comment: When you use `fetch()`, it returns the server's response. This will be explained in the tutorial.

Comment: `calculation()` should return JSON. A Flask tutorial will show how to do that.